# mybatis create temp table from result set

Tags: java, mysql, mybatis

I have a query that select a set from one database and would like to turn that into a temp table that I can transform with some aggregate functions. I would like to do this in memory using MyBatis, and I can't for the life of me seem to get it sorted out. In my mapper xml, I have:

```
<select id="selectExample" resultType="POJOclass">
    SELECT DISTINCT anon_cookie,
    search,
    site
    FROM
    T1
    WHERE
    is_cookied_user = 1
    and is_iab_robot = 0
    and is_pattern_match_robot = 0
    and has_site_search_phrase = 1
    and day_dt >= current_date - 1
</select>
```

In my java class I am retrieving this as a list of the bean class,

> `List<POJO> list = selectList("selectExample", className);`

I would like to find a way to query this result set, either as map, or casting it to the POJO class or perhaps creating a temp table. I can't seem to find a good way to do this using MyBatis... any suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you just use a single query to perform aggregation instead of creating a temporary table? The RDBMS is there so that it lift most of the heavy work from your application, just take advantage of it. And since you are using mybatis it should be easy. Failing that, have a look at [JooQ](http://www.jooq.org)...

Comment: that looks pretty cool and i dont doubt it's easier than mybatis, but I'm a little stuck on what i can use here. also, this is coming from one datasource and going to be sent to another, so I have to hold and requery in memory for these transformations....